# GatsbyJS Scroll to target when navigating to a new page

Tags: gatsby, anchor-scroll

I am using gatsby-plugin-anchor-links in my GatsbyJS application to navigate to a different page to a specific target. The application works perfectly on desktop, but on mobile devices when navigating to a selected page instead of scrolling to the id target, the page opens at on the same scrolling point as previous page and not scrolling to the target.

```
<AnchorLink to={`/services#${serviceId}`}>Service</AnchorLink>
```

I tried using shouldUpdateScroll in gatsby-browse.js but the only behaviour i could achieve was either nothing or that the page always opens at the top. Any suggestions to how to make it work? Or why it does not work only on mobile devices?